# how to ignore a newLine character in the compare script as below

Tags: bash, awk, compare

```
    #!/bin/bash

    function compare {
    for file1 in /dir1/*.csv
    do
    file2=/dir2/$(basename "$file1")

    if [[ -e "$file2" ]]    ### loop only if the file2 with same filename as file1 is present ###
    then
    awk 'BEGIN {FS==","} NR == FNR{arr[$0];next} ! ($0 in arr)' $file1 $file2 > /dirDiff/`echo $(basename "$file1")_diff`
    fi
    done
    }

    function removeNULL {
    for i in /dirDiff/*_diff
    do
    if [[ ! -s "$i" ]]     ### if file exists with zero size ###
    then
    \rm -- "$i"
    fi
    done
    }

    compare
    removeNULL
```

file1 and file2 are the formatted files from two different sources. Source1 is inducing an arbitrary newLine character making one record to split into two records, causing script to fail and generate wrong diff o/p.
I want my script to compare b/w file1 and file2 by ignoring the induced newLine character by Source1. But, I am not sure how my script will identify b/w an actual new record and the manually induced newLine.

```
    file1:-
    11447438218480362,6005560623,6005560623,11447438218480362,5,20160130103044,100,195031,,1,0,00,49256,0
    ,195031_5_00_6,0.1,6;
    11447691224860640,6997557634,6997557634,11447691224860640,601511,20160130103457,500,195035,,2,0,00,45394,0
    ,195035_601511_00_6,0.5,6;

    file2:-
    11447438218480362,6005560623,6005560623,11447438218480362,5,20160130103044,100,195031,,1,0,00,49256,0,195031_5_00_6,0.1,6;
    11447691224860640,6997557634,6997557634,11447691224860640,601511,20160130103457,500,195035,,2,0,00,45394,0,195035_601511_00_6,0.5,6;
```

Appreciate your support.

Comment: Why dont you use the `diff` command?

Comment: Provide sample of both files you are comparing and expected output

Comment: Add this comment to your question and delete your comment.

Comment: Changes done as advised.

Comment: Is it only in your example files that 2 lines need to be joined when the fist one doesn't end with a `;`?

Answer (score 1):

You could preprocess your file1 joining lines not ending in `;` with the next line:

```
sed -r ":again; /;$/! { N; s/(.+)[\r\n]+(.+)/\1\2/g; b again; }" file1
```

so that file1 and file2 are *comparable*.